# Laravel Eloquent Many to Many get newest date and default value if no record in the pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is the simplified version of table in my project.

Table items

```
| id   | name   |
| ---- | ------ |
| 1    | Apple  |
| 2    | Orange |
| 3    | Mango  |
```

Table pricing_groups

```
| id   | name    | deleted |
| ---- | ------- | ------- |
| 1    | Reguler | 0       |
| 2    | VIP     | 0       |
| 3    | VVIP    | 1       |
```

Table price_lists

```
| id   | item_id | group_id | price | date       |
| ---- | ------- | -------- | ----- | ---------- |
| 1    | 1       | 1        | 100   | 2019-01-20 |
| 2    | 1       | 2        | 120   | 2019-01-20 |
| 3    | 1       | 1        | 110   | 2019-02-01 |
| 4    | 2       | 1        | 80    | 2019-01-31 |
| 5    | 2       | 3        | 120   | 2019-01-10 |
```

Items and PricingGroups are many to many relationship and the pivot table is `price_lists`.

Models: `Item`, `PricingGroup`, `PriceList`

So I want to have an eloquent relation called `prices` in model Item to get the price for each PricingGroups.

```
class Item extends Model {
    public function prices() {
        // what should I put here??
    }
}
```

The output I want is like this:

```
"items": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Apple",
    "prices": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Reguler",
        "price": 110
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "VIP",
        "price": 120
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Orange",
    "prices": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Reguler",
        "price": 80
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "VIP",
        "price": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mango",
    "prices": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Reguler",
        "price": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "VIP",
        "price": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note:

- Show active pricing groups with `price=0` if there is no record of
  the item in `price_lists`. See Orange-VIP and Mango case.
- Get the    newest price. See Apple-Reguler case.

Is this possible?

Comment: So in your imaginary scenario is it possible for an item to have two different prices on a single pricing_group?

Comment: @MojtabaHn Yes, like the apple-reguler. But the output need to show the newest price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
/*define the relationship like this*/
  public function price_groups(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(PricingGroup::class,'price_lists','item_id','group_id')->withPivot(['price','date']);
  }

public static function prices($date = null){

    /*get all available pricing groups*/
    $availablePricingGroups = PricingGroup::where('deleted',false)
      ->select('id','name')
      ->get()
      ->toArray();

    /*eager load*/
    $itemPriceGroups = self::with('price_groups')
      ->get()
      ->map(function($item) use ($date,$availablePricingGroups){

      /*sort by date, latest date on top*/
      $priceGroups = $item->price_groups->sortByDESC(
        function($priceGroup){
          return $priceGroup->pivot->date;
        })
        ->filter(function($priceGroup) use ($date){
          /*filter out deleted and greater than $date price group*/
          return $priceGroup->deleted == false && $priceGroup->pivot->date <= ($date??date('Y-m-d'));
        })->groupBy('id')
        ->map(function($priceGroup){
          /*latest price group is still on the top*/
          /*group them together then select the first price group*/
          return $priceGroup->first();
      })->toArray();

      /*iterate through $availablePricingGroups and set its price*/
      foreach($availablePricingGroups as $availablePricingGroup){
        $price = 0;
        foreach($priceGroups as $priceGroup){
          if($priceGroup['id'] == $availablePricingGroup['id']){
            $price = $priceGroup['pivot']['price'];
            break;
          }
        }
        $endResultPriceGroups[] = $availablePricingGroup + ['price' => $price];
      }

      return [
        'id' => $item->id,
        'name' => $item->name,
        'prices' => $endResultPriceGroups,
      ];
    });

    return $itemPriceGroups;
  }
```

Comment: Why static? And how do I call this?

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius You can run the function just like this: `Item::prices('2019-01-01')`. The reason I make it static is for easy access to the function and it does not need a instance to be called.

Comment: Sorry for slow response, I'm not feeling well in the last 2 days.
Your code returns json exactly as what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look into the mutators for your object properties.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators

This way you can add an attribute named "Prices" and return them dynamical.

Comment: I think it is not mutators but accessor. I tried that in other case, I added protected $appends for the accessor. But when I do Item::all(), it was doing query for each item. Do you know how to eager load the accessor?

Comment: I want to do this with eloquent relationship because we can just eager load using Item::with('prices')->get();

Comment: Yeah, sorry i meant accessors. When you are dealing with big data you are probably right to load them only when needed. But you could also create a custom collection for your items and insert the function for price-calculation there. This way you could calculate all prices at once without doing it for every single item each. This should save you a lot of queries.

Answer (score 0):

> Get the newest price. See Apple-Reguler case.

You can **customize** your relationship query So you achieve data you want and also it's still a **relationship** (not like accessors):

```php
//Item.php
    public function prices()
    {
        // normal belongsToMany
        return $this->belongsToMany(PricingGroup::class, 'price_lists', 'item_id', 'group_id')
        // customize select statement
            ->selectRaw('pricing_groups.*, price_lists.price')
        // order by item id
            ->orderByRaw('price_lists.price');
    }
```

Output will be

```sql
select pricing_group.*, price_lists.price from "pricing_groups" inner join "price_lists" on "pricing_groups"."id" = "pric
e_lists"."group_id" where "price_lists"."item_id" = ? order by price_lists.price
```

> Show active pricing groups with price=0 if there is no record of the item in price_lists. See Orange-VIP and Mango case.

I don't think it's even possible using eagerLoading.

Comment: Yeah, I tried belongsToMany, but if the price_lists table is empty, the prices will have empty array instead of always contains 2 pricing group with price 0. That is the point of this question (default value if no record in the pivot). Basically to customize the eloquent to use right join instead of inner join. So I guess this is impossible after all.